# Backup syntax error with constructed string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup, errors, syntax

This is doing my head in. What am I missing? Syntax errors with '+' and ;

```
-- Step 1: Perform a database backup
    BACKUP DATABASE iMIS_Prod TO DISK = 
        'G:\SP_Backup_Daily\iMIS_Prod_' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'GETDATE(), 112)' + 
        '.bak' 
    WITH INIT;
```

[image: -- Step 1: Perform a database backup BACKUP DATABASE iMIS_Prod TO DISK = 'G:\SP_Backup_Daily\iMIS_Prod_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'GETDATE(), 112)' + '.bak' WITH INIT;]

Answer (score 4):

The [`BACKUP` syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql#-disk--tape--url---physical_device_name--physical_device_name_var--nul-) does not support constructed strings:

> { DISK | TAPE | URL} = { 'physical_device_name' | @physical_device_name_var | 'NUL' }

Only a single string literal or variable can be provided.

Store your constructed string in a variable first, or use dynamic SQL.

Or use one of the tools and scripts to automate much of your backup process, for example [SQL Server Backup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) by Ola Hallengren.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a calculated string directly in a `BACKUP` or `RESTORE` statement.

But contrary to popular understanding, **you *can* use a variable**, you do **not** need dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @file nvarchar(260) =
    N'G:\SP_Backup_Daily\iMIS_Prod_' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), GETDATE(), 112) + 
    N'.bak';

BACKUP DATABASE iMIS_Prod
TO DISK = @file
WITH INIT;
```